# mysql - move rows from one table to another or update

Tags: php, mysql

PLOT : i have a PAD websites with 2 DB's : submitdata and maindata .
The submitdata DB has all the columns as maindata DB plus another 3 columns :

MAINDATA COLUMNS     : name link email website .... progid
SUBMITDATA COLUMNS : name link email website .... progid, backlink, affiliateid

I must MOVE all rows from submitdata DB to maindata DB but only IF backlink !='' and IF affiliateid != $affiliateid .

Another problem is if the progid is allready in the maindata DB and it this case I must UPDATE that row with the new data 
... another problem is that i have about 40.000 rows so SELECT * FROM submitdata kinda kills my computer .

Any ideea on how to do that in PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM submitdata;
```

Perhaps it will tell you which fields you can give an INDEX to (this could speed up the query time drastically). Then, if you're not going to move records whose backlink and affiliateid fields are empty, then you can reduce the result set from the query by adding a `WHERE` clause.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM submitdata WHERE backlink <> "" AND affiliateid <> ""');
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $newResult = mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT name,progid FROM maindata WHERE progid = %d', $row['progid']));
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($newResult);
        if ($row2) {
            // do UPDATE query
        } else {
            // do INSERT query
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: uuhuuu... that is some nice code ! thanks A BUNCH ! will post back results.. thanks again !

Comment: you're welcome! hope it works out..let me know if there are any discrepancies.

Comment: Yes man, got it working . still having some problems with the execution time and I'm still overloading the server, but hey .. it works like a charm for moving data from one table to another .. hehe ! :) also added a delete line after update and insert .

Answer (score 1):

You can take MySQL help and have it do all the work instead of you doing it in application layer.  Build the query and then submit it with PHP/Perl etc.

```
INSERT INTO MAINDATA
(col1, col2, col3....)
SELECT col1, col2... FROM
(
    SELECT col1, col2...
    FROM SUBMITDATA SD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MAINDATA MD
      ON SD.key1 = MD.key1 and SD.key2 = MD.key
    WHERE
          SD.backlink <> ''
      AND SD.affiliate <> '$affiliatiid'
) ND
ON DUPLICATE KEY
   SET update_col1 = col1
      ,update_col2 = ...
```

Basically the subquery is getting all rows which meet the condition that backtick != '' and affiliate != affiliateid.  MySQL will try to insert them into MainData and if the row already exists (based in PK/UK) it will update the columns you have given in SET clause.

Note: The method will work provided both DBs are under one mysql server.